# How can an abstract class return an ArrayList of the subclass object?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm trying to return an array list of the subclass object

Suppose

```
abstract class Foo {
    protected abstract ArrayList<Foo> getAlotOfMyself();
};
```

Is a super class where it's sub-classes need to return an array of themselves,
for example it's sub-class:

```
class Bar extends Foo{
   public ArrayList<Bar> getAlotOfMyself(){
      // Do the interesting stuff
   }
};
```

However this doesn't work because of java, `ArrayList<Foo>` is not the same type as `ArrayList<Bar>` even if `Bar` is a subclass of `Foo`

I've tried changing the ArrayList in Foo to `ArrayList<? extends Foo>` but it seems to only work as long as Foo is not an abstract class (and therefore `getAlotOfMyself()` is implemented in `Foo`), it doesn't compile saying :
`cannot convert from ArrayList<capture#1-of ? extends Foo> to ArrayList<Foo>`.

The reason the causes that error is this

```java
void interestingFunction(Foo foo){
    ArrayList<Foo> alot = foo.getAlotOfMyself(); // the compile error happens here
}
```

and of course this function is only called on `Bar` and other sub-classes

Comment: In what class is your "interestingFunction"?

Comment: It's in a third class that acts like a wrapper.

Comment: Well, I'm not certain if I did what you wanted.  Perhaps you can look at it and get some ideas.  Or perhaps **Arvind** did what you wanted.

Comment: `ArrayList<? extends Foo>` absolutely *does* work.  But if your function returns that, then you must assign the returned value to a variable with the same generic type:  `List<? extends Foo> alot = foo.getAlotOfMyself();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it does what you want.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SubclassStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar b = new Bar();
        b.interestingFunction(b);
    }

}

abstract class Foo {
    public String name;
    public Foo() {
    }
    public Foo (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    protected abstract ArrayList<? extends Foo> getAlotOfMyself();
    public void interestingFunction(Foo foo) {
        System.out.println(foo.getAlotOfMyself());
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public ArrayList<Bar> getAlotOfMyself() {       
        return new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Bar("I am Bar")));
    }
    public Bar() {
        super();
    }
    public Bar (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```